# how to reallocate the size of an array inside a structure in C?

Tags: c

This is the code that I have to dynamically declaring an array inside a structure. I am  dynamically allocating the array list with a size called 'capacity'. At a later point in my  program, I want to increase the size of my array and re-allocate it. How do I go about it?

```
struct mystruct {
 int x;
 struct y **list;
};
```

wrapper function to declare the array present inside the structure

```
struct mystruct *mystruct_init()
{
    struct mystruct *mystruct = calloc(1, sizeof(*mystruct));

    // loop through and allocate memory for each element in list
    mystruct->list = calloc(1, sizeof(struct y *) * mystruct->list_length);

    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        mystruct->list[i] = calloc(1, sizeof(struct y));

    return mystruct;
}
```

calling the wrapper function

```
struct mystruct *h1 = mystruct_init();
```

My question is, how do I use the realloc function to increase the size of list (double the value of  capacity)? It would be really nice if someone could help me out.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc

Comment: @SethCarnegie your edit killed a needed bracket.

Comment: @Till whoops, fixed, indentation you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assume you have `int oldsize`:

```
struct y **newlist=realloc(h1->list,oldsize*2*sizeof(struct y*));
if (!newlist) return -1;//error
h1->list=newlist;
int i;
for (i=oldsize;i<2*oldsize;i++) h1->list[i]=calloc(1,sizeof(struct y));
```

Comment: @asaeir : I am getting this error on the re-alloc line                 ** glibc detected *** ./compareDocs: realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0000000000603030 ***.....                                             any idea what this could be about?